# What is the (default) Cache size limit in Play Framework when using Ehcache and/or Caffeine?

Tags: playframework, ehcache, caffeine-cache

Recently I switched my Play Framework-based project from **Ehcache** to **Caffeine**, because the Play documentation for version 2.8 says "For in-process caching Caffeine is typically the best choice."

Now, I implemented a little "test" to see how many items can be added to the cache before *some* items are evicted. The test simply adds more and more items to the cache (***without*** an explicit expiration) in a loop, checking whether all previosuly inserted items still are available after each insert operation, until at least one previously inserted item is detected to be missing.

With **Ehcache** I found that the limit apparently is 10,000 items. After adding *that* many items to the cache, some "old" items start to disappear from the cache. So my conclusion is that *Ehcache*, by default, has a fixed size limit of 10,000 items. With **Caffeine**, on the other hand, there seems to be **no** limit at all! I kept the test running for a very long time, but even after inserting ~1 million items, still *no* previously inserted items had been evicted. At that point I stopped the test.

So, does **Caffeine**, unlike *Ehcache*, not have a size limit by default? Will it keep on accumulating items until, eventually, my application crashes with "out of memory" error, or is there some logic in *Caffeine* that evicts items in "low memory" situations? Is it advisable to configure an explicit cache size limit when using *Caffeine*? I would think so. But then, why Play doesn't do it by default?

---

Unfortuantely, the [Cache documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaCache) of Play Framework doesn't make clear at all which ***default*** settings Play uses with Ehcache and/or Caffeine. Also, a list of available Cache options in the Play configuration (and the respecitive default values) would be really helpful...

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be the defaults set by Play's integrations.

For ehcache, they have a configuration file [ehcache-default.xml](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/cache/play-ehcache/src/main/resources/ehcache-default.xml) with a maximum of 10,000 entries and an expiration time of 120 seconds.

For caffeine, they have a configuration file [reference.conf](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/cache/play-caffeine-cache/src/main/resources/reference.conf) that specifies no constraints. A [maximum-size](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/cache/play-caffeine-cache/src/main/java/play/cache/caffeine/CaffeineParser.java) may be set to limit the number of entries.

The Caffeine library does not have any implicit (arbitrary) defaults, as that might be surprising and most often be incorrect. If a size limit is specified, then the cache is allowed to grow slightly above the threshold in order to support concurrent writes (else all serializing against an exclusive lock), but won't suffer runaway growth due to applying back pressure.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at the configuration files. This really should be linked in the Play Cache documentation! Anyway, if the Caffeine cache does **not** have a size limit by default - at least in Play Framework - what happens if more and more items accumulate over time? Will my application eventually (even if it may take a long time) run out of memory? If so, then the default of "unlimited" size (in Play) seems like a really bad idea. Also given that Ehcache ***does*** have an explicit size limit.

Comment: Yeah, maybe open an issue on Play’s side to suggest a documentation fix and warning if the cache is not bounded?